# Issues with identifying and encoding urls

Tags: javascript, url

I'm having issues with parsing/manipulating URI:

**Problem Statement:**

> I want to encode f[users.comma] and return it.

> [Case-1]  I get an url from backend service, encode f[users.comma] and return it.

> [Case-2]  I get an url from backend service and f[users.comma] is already encoded. So don't double encode and return it.

**Expected Output:**

```
`/demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]=%22Abbeville%2C+Georgia%22`
```

**Code:**

```
const encodedExample = `/demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]=%22Abbeville%2C+Georgia%22` // the last param is encoded

const regularExample2 = `/demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]="Abbeville, Georgia"` // 

const specialEncode = (url) => {
          for (let queryParam of urlObj) {
            const [urlKey, urlValue] = queryParam

            // Check to see if url contains f[users.comma]
            if (urlKey.includes('f[')) {
              urlObj.set(urlKey, encodeURI(urlValue))
            }
          }

          return urlObj.toString() // doesn't seem to work 
}
```

I feel like I am going offroad with my approach. I'd appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the backend service returns an encoded or decode url

We can first decode the url from the backend service (this won't produce any exceptions if url is already encoded)

```js
const encodedExample = `/demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]=%22Abbeville%2C+Georgia%22` // the last param is encoded

const regularExample2 = `/demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]="Abbeville, Georgia"` 

const specialEncode = (url) => {
  let decodedUrl = decodeURI(url);
  let encodedUrl = encodeURI(decodedUrl);
  
  // fix "f[users.comma]" because encodeURI will encode the [ and ] as well
  encodedUrl = encodedUrl.replace("f%5Busers.comma%5D", "f[users.comma]")
  
  console.log(encodedUrl);
  return encodedUrl;
}

specialEncode(encodedExample); // logs and returns: /demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]=%22Abbeville%252C+Georgia%22

specialEncode(regularExample2); // logs and returns: /demo/bigquery/order_items?fields=users.email&f[users.comma]=%22Abbeville%252C+Georgia%22
```

The code above works fine for both encoded and decoded urls